# Linear dilatation

Tags: thermodynamics

$$ \delta L = L \alpha \delta\theta$$
Is the equation of linear dilatation (Approximately). Just now raise a doubt about this equation:
[image]

See this image, imagine that the bar was initially with its ends on the red lines, and so the bar expanded, by let's say L/6 in each side.
I need to use $$ \delta L = L/6 $$ or $$ \delta L = L/3 $$
?
Mathematically i know it should be the second option, but i am not sure if i am interpreting right. Maybe if the bar is free in its sides, one expansion in one direction occurs with one expansion in the opposite direction, so that $$ \delta L$$ in the equation is just with respect to one side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temperature is a monotonic function of the average molecular kinetic energy of a substance. When a substance is heated, molecules begin to vibrate and move more, usually creating more distance between themselves.

When you heat a rod, the length of the rod will increase (in a homogeneous manner). In the formula, $\delta L$ is a change in length of the rod ie. Final minus initial.

In your example, If you heat up the rod, the length increase for each part (distance between each molecule will change) and thus you will take a total change in length that is $L/3$.

Note that we are talking about linear expansion, so it's not possible that the length will increase differently at different parts of the rod. So It doesn't matter How you take increment. Just mark two  points before and after the heating and note the increment.